# Android Firebase cloud function - delete user using email

Tags: android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

i'm trying to delete a user from firebase auth using a cloud function which is triggered when i delete the document of the user. this is a workaround to enable one client "admin" permissions to delete other users without admin SDK. in the document i store the users email. how do i delete the user from auth using the email?

it should be something like this:

```
exports.sendDelVolunteer = functions.firestore.document('Users/{messageId}').onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const doc = snap.data();
    const user = admin.auth().getUserByEmail(doc.email).then(function(userRecord) {
        return admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid).then(function() {
            console.log('Successfully deleted user');
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
          });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });
});
```

currently i get the following error: "error    Each then() should return a value or throw"

thanks!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3p9R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a top-level `return` statement.

```
exports.sendDelVolunteer = functions.firestore.document('Users/{messageId}').onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const doc = snap.data();
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(doc.email).then(function(userRecord) {
        return admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid)
    });
});
```

Aside from that this looks like a good approach. Just make sure that only your administrator(s( can delete these documents, as otherwise you still have a security hole.